# Center View below another View

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a RelativeLayout in order to place a View. Now i want to add one more View that is below the first View, and shall be centered referred to the first View. 
But there seems to be no option thats called something like android:layout_alignCenter..
How can i achieve this task?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="top">

            <TextView
        android:text="Blaa"
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
            <TextView
        android:text="Foo"
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1"
            --- NEED STH THAT ALIGNS THIS SECOND VIEW CENTRAL UNDER THE FIRST VIEW --
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That would align my View central in the parent, but i would like to align it central reffered to a second View - Sorry the question was a bit ambiguous

Comment: With `android:gravity="center"` you have them both centered, therefore TextView2 is centered below TextView1.

Comment: Yes i could do that and have done it before, but i want to be able to move around my TextView1 and TextView2 shall stay centered below TextView1. If i add for example another margin to TextView1 i dont want to change anything in TextView2, it shall just move with TextView1 and stay centered below relative to it. I sort of want to 'glue' them together

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but still unanswered, so...

You can have both the beginning and the end of both views aligned in the same way. This will override the width property of the second one and will make it wide as the first, but will also move it with the first one. If you want to center the second view, you may use gravity or padding. The second view goes so:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Foo" />
```

Comment: Excellent! :) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Blaa" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Foo" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked for an answer too. I think the best option is to put them in a LinearLayout.. I'm not sure but i believe inflating a lot of layouts is a intensive process so it's probably not the best option but it's the only thing i can think of.